# i want symbol right in data table with ngif

Tags: angular, font-awesome

### example

```
I want output   ✔ ✔  

but this output ✔ 
                ✔
```

### table data

use font awesome

```
    <tr *ngFor="let Patients of Patients | async">
        <div *ngIf="Patients.firstStatus == '2' ">
             <td class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-check"> </td>
        </div>

        <div *ngIf="Patients.secondStatus == '2' ">
             <td class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-check"> </td>
        </div>
              
        <div *ngIf="Patients.secondStatus == '2' ">
             <td class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-check"> </td>    
        </div>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Your HTML structure is incorrect. You shouldn't wrap `<td>` with `<div>`

Answer (score 0):

You can modify ngfor and that will work.

```
<tr>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let Patients of Patients | async">
    <td class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-check" *ngIf="Patients.firstStatus == '2' "></td>
    <td class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-check" *ngIf="Patients.secondStatus == '2' "> </td>
    <td class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-check" *ngIf="Patients.secondStatus == '2' "> </td>    
  </ng-container>  
</tr>
```

Or You can use span If table and td is not required Like below:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let Patients of Patients | async">
    <span class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-check" *ngIf="Patients.firstStatus == '2' "></span>
    <span class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-check" *ngIf="Patients.secondStatus == '2' "> </span>
    <span class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-check" *ngIf="Patients.secondStatus == '2' "> </span>    
  </ng-container>
```